# jquery ui dynamic dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, dialog

I am fairly new to js and jquery. I basically want to be able to change the table and id variables from an onClick event or something appended to the `<a>` this way I can modify the variables with php later on. This is just proof of concept, and doesnt seem to be working since I made modifications. Is there a way that I can pass variables from the a to the function?

OVERALL GOAL: I want to have an inline onclick that will pass id and table names from loadMe to the function and display table_render.php?id=someid&table=sometable in the dialog box.

```
  <script>
    $(function loadMe(table, id) {
        $( "#dialog-view" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 700,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
        $( "#create-view" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-view" ).load("table_render.php?id=" + id + "&table=" + table + "").dialog("open");
        });
    });
    </script>
    <a href="" id="create-view" onClick="loadMe(testimonials,1)">Some text</a>
    <div id="dialog-view" title="">
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm confused: it looks like you already are passing two variables (testimonials and 1)?

Comment: yea. table name and id. just proof of concept so i can implement it into my php.

Comment: Right, so your example code already passes two variables, but your question is "Is there a way that I can pass variables from the a to the function?" ... that doesn't make sense.  Why do you need to know how to do something you clearly already know how to do (because you're doing it)?

Comment: Well it isnt working so idk what the problem is.. like if im passing the variables correctly .etc

Comment: The jQuery click handler may be conflicting with the onclick attribute. Inline handlers like onclick attributes are tricky to deal with and unnecessary. The event-handling functions built into jQuery are much more powerful and easier to use.

Comment: yes but it has to be inline for my php since i have a do while region. otherwise i would have to recreate the above code for every href in the region

Comment: Yes, I'm confused as well. Maybe if you backed up a bit and explained the overall goal? So instead of "here's the answer but it doesn't work" a bit more of "and this what I'd like to have in the end." perhaps we are fixing something that can be built out differently?

Comment: updated the question. I hope its easier to understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hooking up the event twice, once via onclick and once via jQuery.  You need to pick one.

If you pick the jQuery way (recommended) you're going to get the jQuery arguments (which is just one arg, event).  However, jQuery will set `this` to the element that triggered the event (in this case, your A tag).  You can use that to get data off of the A tag.

For instance, if you wanted the ID of the A that got clicked, you could do this in your handler:

```
var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
```

If you want to store some arbitrary info (eg. "tableName") for each A tag, you can either use the HTML 5 data attributes (preferable), or just make up your own attributes (which will work, but is "bad form").  For instance:

```
<a tableName='testimonials'>

var clickedFoo = $(this).attr('tableName');
```

or (a little better):

```
<a data-tableName='5'>

var clickedTableName = $(this).attr('data-tableName');
// Also, I believe this would work:
var clickedTableName = $(this).data('tableName');
```

*** EDIT ***

Just to try and clarify a little further, the basic overall idea is this:

1) You write out your A tags to the page, via PHP

1A) As you write them out, you put whatever data is specific to them on the A tag, in the form of an attribute or attributes (eg. `id='foo' data-bar='baz'`).

2) You also write out some Javascript code that says "hey, whenever an A tag gets clicked, run this function"

3) Inside the function that you hooked up to the A tag's click event, you use the `this` variable (which points to the A tag itself) to get the data (the "variables") that you need

3A) For instance, you could use the JQuery "attr" method: `$(this).attr('id')`

4) Profit! (or at least do something useful with the data you just got)

Comment: im aware how to do this. but for the sake of figuring out what the problem is i simplified it so i dont have to deal w php right now.

Comment: P.S. If the table name is something you can find in the DOM, you can just get it that way instead; for instance you could do `$(this).parents('table:first').attr('name');`

Comment: P.P.S Storing data in the DOM may be the most convenient thing for you (especially as a PHP-er), but in terms of general JS design you're almost certainly better off storing that data in the Javascript somehow.

Comment: i understand where you are going. but my implementation skills are a bit... lacking. is there a way to trigger a function from the a href like in my example and pass the variables? because as of yet it seems as tho the variables are not getting passed. is that because i didnt define var id?

Comment: but i will try it this way first and see.

Comment: So, with the jQuery version, you don't pass variables directly at all.  Instead jQuery sets "this" inside your function, and you get whatever variables you need from that.  Of course, to be able to do that you have to put the information on to the A tag in the first place, as an "id" or "data-tableName" or whatever attribute.

Answer (score 1):

so i got it working... heres the solution

```
function createViewer(id, table) {
        var id;
        var table;
        $("#dialog-view").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width:650,
            minHeight:400,
            show:{effect: "fade", duration: 500},
            hide:"clip",
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#dialog-view").load("table_render.php?id=" + id + "&table=" + table + "").dialog("open");
    };
```

And the inline code

```
<a href="#" onMouseDown="createViewer(<?php echo $row_testimonials['id'];?>,'testimonials');">View Quote</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to put `$(document).ready()`around you functions initialising the dialog and binding the onclick event. Then open the dialog inside the callback of your ajax request.

That way you could dismiss the onclick attribute with the loadFunction, I guess. (tired)

something like:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="trigger" data-my-id="123" data-my-table="myTable">
  trigger
</a>

<div id="dialog">
 Dialog Contents....
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 700,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#trigger").click(function() {

        var id = parseInt( $(this).attr('data-my-id');
        var table = $(this).attr('data-my-table');

        $("#dialog").load("table_render.php?id=" + id + "&table=" + table + "", 
          function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
          });
    });

});​
```

should do the trick.

Comment: ok i see what you are doing. but how do i pass my id and table from an inline a onclick to this?

Comment: you could store those in data-attributes, rather then in the conclick and access them using jquerys `attr()`  (edited the answer)

Comment: yea thats what @machine said above. but i prefer to do it the way i posted as an answer. for simplicity